# How to setup Intelisense on VS Code for ROS C++

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`#include "ros/ros.h"` is even underlined in green. I have this added to the c_cpp_properties.json file. I also installed the ROS extension (which I'm not sure does anything).

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "path": [
                    "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/cir-kit/devel/include",
                    "/opt/ros/kinetic/include",
                    "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/ackermann/src/twist_to_ackermann-1/include",
                    "/usr/include"
                ]
            },
            "includePath": [
                "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/cir-kit/devel/include",
                "/opt/ros/kinetic/include",
                "/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/ackermann/src/twist_to_ackermann-1/include",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/include/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/linux",
                "/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
            ],
            "name": "Linux",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```

When I hover over top of the include, it gives me an error:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (/home/ben/workspaces/ROS/ackermann/src/twist_to_ackermann-1/src/twist_to_ackermann.cpp) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
cannot open source file "x86intrin.h" (dependency of "ros/ros.h")
```

Everything else ROS works... This in Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282295/how-to-setup-intelisense-on-vs-code-for-ros-c++/) by [horseatinweeds](https://answers.ros.org/users/33178/horseatinweeds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amos](https://answers.ros.org/users/34051/amos/) on 2018-03-29**:
I meet the same problem. I find "x86intrin.h" in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include. Add this path to c_cpp_properties.json and #include "ros/ros.h" is OK.

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2020-04-09**:
Have you solved this problem ?

**Comment by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on 2020-10-02**:
There are suggested answers to this problem under [another question](https://answers.ros.org/question/256565/how-to-add-ros-to-path-in-vs-code/#362726).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably doable to set this up manually, but I would recommend to take a look at [wiki/IDEs - Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Visual_Studio_Code_.28VSCode.29). It has a link to an extension that should take care of all of this for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2021-05-11**:
"The extension does not require additional configuration" is the biggest lie ever!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-11**:
Thanks for the feedback.

It would be more valuable if you could give your feedback to Microsoft, on their issue tracker.

Your comment here will most likely not be read by many people.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2021-05-11**:
As Samarth mentioned in his answer, [this blog post](https://erdalpekel.de/?p=157) really helps getting it setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS extension mentioned in wiki/IDEs includes a task to update the `c_cpp_properties.json` (adding ROS paths to `includePath`), but in my experience that feature is brittle.

It is much more robust to let catkin handle that by getting CMake to export `compile_commands.json` during the build process. Then you can point C++ IntelliSense to that `compile_commands.json` as an alternative to modifying the `includePath`. [VSCode reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)

More details (copied from my [here](https://samarth-robo.github.io/blog/2020/12/03/vscode_ros.html)):

[This blog post by Erdal](https://erdalpekel.de/?p=157) gives nice step-by-step instructions.

I had to make one change, though: Instead of creating the new `catkin_make` task, I used the default `catkin: make` task that the VSCode ROS extension automatically creates.

For IntelliSense to work, CMake in the `catkin: make` task needs to be configured to generate `compile_commands.json`, as the blog mentions. But the `catkin: make` task command cannot be edited. However, it simply runs `catkin build` (or `catkin_make`, whichever command you normally use to build ROS workspaces) under the hood. So I pre-configure catkin for my ROS workspace like so:

```bash
$ cd catkin_ws
$ catkin config -a --cmake-args -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```

Note that I use [`catkin-tools`](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/), not the simple `catkin` that ships with ROS.

The above command caches the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` CMake argument in the catkin configuration. As mentioned in the blog, this CMake argument causes it to create `compile_commands.json` in `catkin_ws/build/<package_name>/`. If you point IntelliSense to this file using the `compileCommands` field in `c_cpp_properties.json` as mentioned in the blog, everything works.

---

Originally posted by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) with karma: 33 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works for me:

1. In .vscode folder and in c_cpp_properties.json file
   add "/opt/ros/distribution_name/include" in includePath, including quotes.
   Change "distribution_name" to your ROS distribution.
2. Restart vs code.

---

Originally posted by [Madhukar](https://answers.ros.org/users/78230/madhukar/) with karma: 31 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

Use the [catkin-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=betwo.b2-catkin-tools) extension.

While its documentation lists all important prerequisites, the most important one is the presence of the compile_commands.json files that can be generated by adding this to the catkin config:

```bash
catkin config --cmake-args -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

Note that an initial `catkin build` is required for these files to be generated. After that the extension will select the compile_commands.json to consider for full IntelliSense support.